# how to solve extra `table` & `modifiable` merging issue while while json parsing as OpenStruct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1, ruby-2.5, openstruct

```
JSON.parse(response, object_class: OpenStruct) rescue response
```

My rails application has above line of code which is causing an weird issue. Here `response` is coming from an external API call and looks like following

```
"{\"payable_amount\":80.0,\"qr_data\":{\"data\":\"upi://pay?pa=paytm-@paytm&&mc=&tr=&am=80&cu=INR&paytmqr=\",\"image\":\"+1OqeGDVfgX5Thh2X4Yf2P8B8/it24m51v9gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==\"},\"transaction_id\":387400583,\"success\":true}"
```

WheneverI am running the app as a whole the result after JSON.parse() looks like the following:

```
"{\"table\":{\"payable_amount\":80.0,\"qr_data\":{\"table\":{\"data\":\"upi://pay?pa=paytm-@paytm\\u0026\\u0026mc=5411\\u0026tr=\\u0026am=80\\u0026cu=INR\\u0026paytmqr=\",\"image\":\"+1OqeGDVfgX5Thh2X4Yf2P8B8/it24m51v9gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==\"},\"modifiable\":true},\"transaction_id\":387400583,\"success\":true},\"modifiable\":true}"
```

`table` & `modifiable` fields are unexpected and `'&'` are also messed up, weird thing is it's not happening when I am executing the code line by line from rails console.

I have fixed the issue by just doing `JSON.parse(response).deep_symbolize_keys!` but still confused about the issue.

Comment: Not sure I understand this question as "the result after `JSON.parse` would not "look like" that. What you have posted is a String which happens to be in JSON format; however that is not what the result of `JSON.parse` would be. Based on your initial code block the result would be an `OpenStruct`. Can you please provide more clarity as to what the implementation looks like that produces the output you are referencing?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to help if you included the implementation that results in the confusing result.

Anyway, it looks like `to_json` is being called on the OpenStruct object somewhere:

```
> response = "{\"payable_amount\":80.0,\"qr_data\":{\"data\":\"upi://pay?pa=paytm-@paytm&&mc=&tr=&am=80&cu=INR&paytmqr=\",\"image\":\"+1OqeGDVfgX5Thh2X4Yf2P8B8/it24m51v9gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==\"},\"transaction_id\":387400583,\"success\":true}"
> parsed_response = JSON.parse(response, object_class: OpenStruct)
> parsed_response.to_json
=> "{\"table\":{\"payable_amount\":80.0,\"qr_data\":{\"table\":{\"data\":\"upi://pay?pa=paytm-@paytm\\u0026\\u0026mc=\\u0026tr=\\u0026am=80\\u0026cu=INR\\u0026paytmqr=\",\"image\":\"+1OqeGDVfgX5Thh2X4Yf2P8B8/it24m51v9gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==\"}},\"transaction_id\":387400583,\"success\":true}}"
```